# Почему после перезагрузки страницы выполняется только 1 запрос к БД?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

При первой загрузке страницы, после старта сервера, выполняются оба запроса, после перезагрузке страницы только первый.

app.js

```
var connection = require('./lib/db');

global.connection = connection;
```

db.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'hype',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if(err) throw err;

    console.log('Connected');
});

module.exports = connection;
```

index.js

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    let data = {};
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM hc_posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        data.posts = result;
    });
    connection.query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hc_posts", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        data.amount = result[0]['COUNT(*)'] + 1;
    });

    res.render('index', { data: data });
});
```

Comment: На первый взгляд должны отправляться оба. Чем докажите, что отправляется только 1-й?

Answer (score 0):

Я вижу тут 2 проблемы.

1. Через 1 коннект в mysql должен ходить 1 запрос. Именно поэтому нужно использовать пул коннектов.
2. Вы явно не знаете как работают коллбэки и асинхронщина в js. У вас должно быть что то вроде:

```js
router.get('/foo', async (req, res, next) => {
    const answers = await Promise.all([
        pool.query('select 1'),
        pool.query('select 2'),
    ]);

    const data = {
        posts: answers[0],
        amount: answers[1],
    };

    res.render('index', { data });
});
```

Вместо этого вы не дожидаясь результата пытаетесь вернуть какие-то данные.